# Adding gravity to (Elcott07 "Stable, Circulation-Preserving, Simplicial Fluids")

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, simulations

The paper is quite popular, and I thought to implement it as an exercise for DEC. I added an initial vortex force, and indeed it's preserved throughout the simulation due to incompressibility and inviscidness.

I'd like to add a gravity force, as mentioned in section 4.2. However, eq. (6) adds the curl of a force to the vorticity. Since gravity is a constant force, nothing is added...?

https://doi.org/10.1145/1189762.1189766

Answer (score 0):

Elcott07 considers a 1-phase simulation, e.g. water only. Then, gravity indeed has no effect, else it would violate incompressiblity.

In a 2-phase simulation, e.g. water/air, due to boundary conditions, gravity will exact a force on the boundary between the two mediums.